# ant reads values from properties entries and write back in a new line

Tags: java, ant

In my Java project, I have three values in an existing properties file (version info file): Their values will be different for each build.

```
value1=1
value2=2
value3=3
```

I want to use ant to read them and write them back at the end of the same properties file as this format: if the line exist, overwrite it.

```
values=value1.value2.value3  i.e. values=1.2.3
```

How to do this?

---

**Resolved:**

I have figured out:

1. use `<loadproperties>` to load the properties.
2. use **value1**, **value2** and **value3** as `properties` with ${value1} to get value and then write to the file with `<propertyfile>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't actually need to read the original properties, you could do this in one step:

```
<replaceregexp
    file="foo.properties"
    flags="g"
    match="value(\d)"
    replace="\1"
/>
```